deploye hadoop cluster in Kubernetes
hellow every one , I have question can any want tell me if this architect that I want to do is possible and how can I start :

create a hadoop cluster compose of 3 nodes ( 2 data Node + 1 NameNode) using K8s in production env , the image illustrate the config that I want to do :enter image description here


What did you try so far?

I tried to create a StatefulSet for each DataNode and NameNode, along with a PersistentVolume (PV) and PersistentVolumeClaim (PVC) for each pod, but this time it didn’t work.

Add this information + configuration files in to the question
